# Localization of photon

Tags: photons, locality, photon-emission

Is the photon localized at the instant of its Emission (release)?

1. by an accelarating charge
2. by Atom´s emission

Answer (score 4):

Yes and no. It takes a finite time for a given amount of energy to emerge, and the emission process is continuous in time. While the emitter and photon are still interacting, you can't really imagine the photon as an independent thing. But your question also touches on the wave-particle duality. If you have a device which can measure where the photon is with sufficient precision, then at early times in the emission process such a device would only register the presence of a photon at positions close to the emitter.

In the case of spontaneous emission from an atom, if the atomic state natural lifetime is $\tau$ then the emitted light comes out as a pulse whose amplitude decays exponentially with characteristic time $\tau$ (e.g. a few nanoseconds for some cases, or seconds, days or even years for others). However a light detector can itself disturb this process, and that is what happens when $\tau$ is long. That is also why people speak of 'quantum jumps'. There is a wavepacket of light of some finite duration, but the detection process may itself impose another timescale, so that it looks as if first there is no photon, and then suddenly there is one. Really what happens here is that there is a non-zero value for the photon wavefunction over a duration $\tau$, giving a finite probability of a photon being detected at any time, and the detector  suddenly announces a 'click' at some time within this interval. It is similar in radioactive decay.

In the case of the photoelectric effect the process of ejecting a photoelectron from a metal surface is fast but not instantaneous.

See also: [What does a photon emitted by an atom "look" like?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/441555/what-does-a-photon-emitted-by-an-atom-look-like)

Comment: I am puzzled by your Statement 'continuos in time'. As I know from the photoeffect ít is instant! Nothing to do with classical waves. So the photon can not have any measures of a Long wave. And so would be released (emitted) instantly e.g. it can have wave properties but is not a wave in any way with some extent. Also the excited state makes a Quantum jump in lower state. A never heard about the time of the jump! Well the Atom stays in excited state as Long as needed but then it does not radiate.

Comment: I extended my answer in response to your query.

Comment: Well I see. But I have two objections about this model. A) it turns out that the Receiver is the reason for the Emission  B) it Looks superluminal - the Receiver clicks and the Emitter undergoes Energy reduction (up to this Moment all is potential - the wavefunction (e.g posibility) spreading out.

Comment: Your reservations are perfectly understandable; what you are noticing is that while the emission process is midway through, i.e. not yet complete, then the emitter and photon are in an entangled state, and all the usual puzzles about entanglement apply.